# Не вводит элементы типа float

Tags: c, список

В дек не вводит элементы типа `float`. Может, кто-то найдет, в чем проблема?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <locale>

struct Node {
    float data;
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;
    struct Node* temp2;
};

struct Node* head;


struct Node* GetNewNode(float x) {
    struct Node* newNode
        = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->data = x;
    newNode->prev = NULL;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}


void InsertAtHead(float x) {
    struct Node* newNode = GetNewNode(x);
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = newNode;
        return;
    }
    head->prev = newNode;
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
}

void DeleteAtHead() {
    struct Node* temp = head;
    if (head != NULL) {
        head = head->next;
        free(temp);
    }

}

void DeleteAtTail() {
    struct Node* temp = head;
    struct Node* temp2 = head;
    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp2 = temp->prev;
    temp2->next = NULL;
    free(temp);

}

void InsertAtTail(float x) {
    struct Node* temp = head;
    struct Node* newNode = GetNewNode(x);
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = newNode;
        return;
    }
    while (temp->next != NULL) temp = temp->next;
    temp->next = newNode;
    newNode->prev = temp;
}


void Print() {
    struct Node* temp = head;
    printf("Forward: ");
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("%f ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}



int main() {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    printf("Введите размер дека: ");
    int razmer, choice;
    scanf_s("%d", &razmer);
    int kol = 0;
    float datain;

    while (true) {

        printf("Menu:\n");
        printf("1) Вставить элемент сверху.\n");
        printf("2) Вставить элемент снизу.\n");
        printf("3) Удалить элемент сверху.\n");
        printf("4) Удалить элемент снизу.\n");
        printf("5) Вывод.\n");
        printf("6) Выход.\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &choice);
        fflush(stdin);


        switch (choice) {

        case 1:
            if (kol < razmer) {
                kol++;
                scanf_s("%f", &datain);
                InsertAtHead(datain);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Размер дека превышен. Будет удалён первый элемент!\n");
                scanf_s("%f", &datain);
                DeleteAtHead();
                InsertAtHead(datain);

            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (kol < razmer) {
                scanf_s("%f", &datain);
                InsertAtTail(datain);

            }
            else
            {
                printf("Размер дека превышен. Будет удалён первый элемент!\n");
                scanf_s("%f", &datain);
                DeleteAtHead();
                InsertAtTail(datain);
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            DeleteAtHead();
            break;
        case 4:
            DeleteAtTail();
            break;
        case 5:
            Print();
            break;
        case 6:
            return 0;
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: В каком смысле "не вводит"?

Comment: Используйте при вводе, как разделитель не `.`, а `,` у вас же локаль русская

Comment: и `fflush` вас не спасет - зациклитесь (ну, это, правда к вопросу не имеет отношения :) )

Comment: @Sublihim Спасибо большое! Проблема была действительно в этом=)